# How to send files in android through bluetooth and store the files without writing retriving code?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am new to bluetooth concept.can any one please explain how the file is transferred in bluetooth(from 1-2) and how it is created with the same name and store the data into 2nd mobile.If it is (2) not a android mobile than how it receives?
Please explain 
thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very brief description:

- Open a BluetoothServerSocket on one of the devices which will act as a server.
- Obtain a BluetoothDevice object (from the BluetoothServerSocket) that represents the remote device.
- Use the BluetoothDevice object to acquire a BluetoothSocket.
- Initiate the connection.
- Use the BluetoothSocket to transfer data:
- Get the InputStream and OutputStream via the BluetoothSocket.
- Read and write data to the streams with read(byte[]) and write(byte[])

A more detailed description and source code examples can be found at [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html).